# Python Errors when Installing LogMeIn Hamachi

Tags: command-line, python, error-handling

When I go to install the beta version of LogMeIn Hamachi for Linux using the .tgz file download, I get this error when I run the install.sh file:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/lib/lsb/install_initd", line 3, in <module>
         import sys, re, os, initdutils
       File "/usr/lib/lsb/initdutils.py", line 18
         raise ValueError, 'need a file or string'
```

I have LSB installed which is a requirement to install Hamachi.  Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Can you post the line after `raise ValueError, 'need a file or string'` please? It provides useful (essential) information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not install the deb package that they provide?

```
wget https://secure.logmein.com/labs/logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.101-1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.101-1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg-configure -a
```

Or, if you have a 64-bit system:

```
wget https://secure.logmein.com/labs/logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.101-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.101-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg-configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an error with `python2` to `python3` compatibility.

```
raise ValueError, 'need a file or string'
```

Is no longer supported in `python3`, deprecated in favour of

```
raise ValueError('need a file or string')
```

Therefore, you should try running this command:

```
sudo sed -i "s/python3/python/" /usr/lib/lsb/install_initd
```

to make sure that the file is run with `python2`